# How to avoid having "whitespace" posts in a site?

Tags: php, post, whitespace

I have this site : http://aasiskos.webpages.auth.gr/1905_YPA/Rating.php . I log in ( user = mpa@mpa.com and pass = 123a ) and then I can add a comment by pushing the green image. I am trying to put a restriction to the "post comment" thing. I want to avoid having comments posted with whitespace (no text). But it doesn't work. The posts that are not whitespace , are not shown either. The problem is under the last "else" thing in the code below. How can i change that ?

```
$link=mysql_connect('localhost', 'student1905','123456');
mysql_select_db('student1905');

$title= $_POST["title"];
$text= $_POST["text"];

if (!$link) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
header("Location:Rating.php"); 
}

if (  ($_POST[title]=" ")     ||       ($_POST[text]=" ")  ) {
header("Location:Rating.php"); 
}
else
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO kritikes (Auxon, Date, Title, Text) VALUE ('',CURDATE(),'$_POST[title]', '$_POST[text]')";
mysql_query($sql);
}

?>
```

Comment: trim trim trim trim trim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `trim()` to take out any leading and trailing white space. examples:

```
 trim('  h i '); //is equal to "h i"
 trim('hello world'); //is equal to "hello world"
```

it does not remove the middle whitespace.

You can use `empty` to check if the string is empty regardless how many whitespace it contains. Examples:

```
 empty(""); //returns true
 empty("  "); //returns true
 empty("  a"); //returns false
```

Comment: This only partially answers the question.

Comment: You gave an even additional explanation for trim. Thank you very much. I believe by sharing our knowledge, is the best way to learn. Just curious, is there any other "function" that removes all the spaces ? For example convert "Hello World  " to ----> "HelloWorld"  ?

In addition, I have a new question here that relates to the same site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722242/letters-appear-out-of-the-comment-box-in-php-site-after-comment-is-added-how-to

Comment: that case you would use regular expression to remove all white space or simply use str_replace(" ", "", $str);

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP's [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to remove white space from the beginning and end of a string. This would easily allow you to evaluate the content.

However, there are several other problems with your code. Firstly, you are redirecting to `Rating.php` if your database connection exists. This will prevent any future code in the PHP from running.

You're also using a deprecated family of functions. `mysql_*` bring serious security implications to the table. You should really consider using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Along with this, your code is open to [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), so you should certainly make sure that you sanitize your inputs.

That having been said, the following code should work for you, but you'll need to make the changes based on my recommendations above regarding `mysql_*` and SQL injection:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'student1905','123456');
mysql_select_db('student1905');

$title= trim($_POST["title"]);
$text = trim($_POST["text"]);

if(!$link) 
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
    if(strlen($title) == 0 || strlen($text) == 0) 
    {
        header("Location:Rating.php"); 
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO kritikes (Auxon, Date, Title, Text) VALUE ('',CURDATE(),'$title', '$text')";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: THANX ! It worked. I just added header("Location:Rating.php"); after the mysql_query($sql); line at the end ;)

Comment: Also, thanx for writting the whole code ;) That helped me a lot. I am a new php site maker :P I have 2 more issues and the site is done :P The one is about the comments. If the letters are too many, they appear to be out of the comment box. If you check now : http://aasiskos.webpages.auth.gr/1905_YPA/Rating.php you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim` to remove any leading or trailing whitespace. Then check if the message is empty (ie. `strlen($message) === 0`).

Comment: This only partially answers the question.

Comment: If he has two questions he should post two questions. Looking at the title, I've answered the question.

Comment: I guess you've never heard of the XY Problem ;)

Comment: Checking for empty input is a step you need to perform regardless of whatever comes after. XY does not apply.

Comment: It does apply. The OP assumes that the entries aren't being inserted (regardless of white space content) because of how he's evaluating it, not because he's redirecting if there's a DB connection. XY definitely comes into play here.

Comment: OPs question is (paraphrasing) _"How do I detect empty posts, and why aren't non-empty posts not being inserted?"_ See that _and_ there? It's not XY. True, I only answered one part of the question but you could argue that it's a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this-

```
if(trim($_POST[title])=="") {
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try updating this line :

```
if (  ($_POST[title]=" ")     ||       ($_POST[text]=" ")  )
```

to :

```
if (  strlen(trim($_POST[title]))== 0    ||       strlen(trim($_POST[text]))== 0  )
```

Comment: No need for `===` here. `strlen` always returns an integer. `==` is sufficient.

Comment: indeed ! Post updated; And your more complete answer upvoted :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. For just spaces, use str_replace: For ex, $string = str_replace(' ',
   '', $string);
2. For all whitespace, use preg_replace:

   $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
3. If you just are dealing with excess whitespace on the beginning or
   end of the string you can use trim(), ltrim() orrtrim() to remove
   that.

Answer (score 0):

Read in your post variables into actual variables, trimming while doing so. Then, do a check to make sure neither of them is an empty string. If neither is empty, then proceed to do your sql query. See example below.

```
$title = trim($_POST['title']);
$text  = trim($_POST['text']);
if($title != '' && $text != '') {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO kritikes (Auxon, Date, Title, Text) VALUE ('',CURDATE(),'$title', '$text')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```