# Letters appear out of the comment box in php site after comment is added. How to limit the shown letters per line?

Tags: php, css

I have made a site here : http://aasiskos.webpages.auth.gr/1905_YPA/Rating.php . You can enter the system in the loginbox by putting the following:

user: mpa@mpa.com
pass: 123a

And if you press the green box , you can add a comment. The thing is that if you write many letters then they appear to be out of the comment box. I have tried everything and I can't thing any useful tags in order to solve the problem. If you scroll down the page you can see that the letters of a comment I made, appear out of the box. How am i going to solve it  and in which page ? The current page (Rating.php) ,the add new comment page (new_comment.php) or in the css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your code to begin with;

- ID's have to be unique according to JS standards
- Your div's arent closed `</div>`

But It's your party

And add to CSS:

```
word-wrap:break-word
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add `word-wrap:break-word` to your CSS.